# Foundation 5 : change total columns just for small

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

Do you know if it is possible to config the number of columns like smartphone (small), tablet (medium) and PC (large)?

Example :

`small: 4 columns`

`tablet and desktop: 12 columns`

`$total-columns work for all device actualy.`

Thank you :)

Comment: Well have you tried research?

Comment: Because i'm pretty sure this is answered!

Comment: Note that I am not asking how to have a div 4 column, I'm looking to make $ total-exchange columns is not equal for small medium and large

Comment: You can use mixin to create your own grid class name instead of small-*.
Read this page first: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

There is just about rules rewrite.

When you specifying `small-12` - on every screen size from small to large your element will have 12 columns width. `small-12 medium-6` will give you 12 on small and 6 on medium and large. So, if you want the element look the same on all devices, just specify the `small-` class.

But, if you wish to have a different number of columns, do the following:

Using Foundation SASS, open settings.scss and uncomment `$total-columns` variable. 
Change the number, compile css, extract `@media only screen` query. Then, change the $total-columns again, compile, extract media query for medium screens. Repeat for the large, etc.